# how can i find where syscall ( some number ) routine?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

I am working on a self compiled linux kernel. The person who modified the kernel has added some syscalls. What I want to do is knowing where does the actual routine (.c file) for the that specific number is i.e. syscall(300), so how would I know where is the routine for the 300 ?

More elaboration: syscall should know what file, which is a compiled .c file, to invoke when I do syscall (300), I want to see that .c file.

I am usuing Ubuntu 9.10 
Look forward for your input,

Comment: Can you reword this: *What I want to do is knowing where does the actual routine for the that specific number is i.e. syscall(300), so how would I know where is the routine for the 300 ?* What do you mean by "where is"? Do you mean what .c file in the kernel contains its implementation? Or what .h file you need to include in your userspace program to use this syscall?

Comment: Done, I hope it is more clear now. Thanks George.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see how the system call implemented on x86_32 (look [there](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.3.1/arch/x86/kernel/entry_32.S#L500)):

```
 500 ENTRY(system_call)
 501        RING0_INT_FRAME                 # can't unwind into user space anyway
 502        pushl_cfi %eax                  # save orig_eax
 503        SAVE_ALL
 504        GET_THREAD_INFO(%ebp)
 505                                        # system call tracing in operation / emulation
 506        testl $_TIF_WORK_SYSCALL_ENTRY,TI_flags(%ebp)
 507        jnz syscall_trace_entry
 508        cmpl $(NR_syscalls), %eax
 509        jae syscall_badsys
 510 syscall_call:
 511        call *sys_call_table(,%eax,4)
 512        movl %eax,PT_EAX(%esp)          # store the return value
 [...]
```

As you see there is a system call dispatch instruction here at line 511:

```
call *sys_call_table(,%eax,4)
```

So, the first thing you'll need to do is to get the `sys_call_table` address. The next thing is to get `$(NR_syscalls)` value. And the last thing is simple - iterate over all the `sys_call_table` values.

If you have `gdb`, `vmlinux` and `/proc/kcore` you can do the following:

```
# gdb vmlinux /proc/kcore
```

Besides that you can use `objdump -rd vmlinux` to dump the disassembly of your kernel.

Answer (score 0):

The file `syscall_table.S` should contain the list.